# How to disable winbind user on linux box

Tags: linux

We have enabled winbind user on our linux box. But we would like to block a common account which we use on windows.

How to disable one account from winbind from logging to linux?

Answer (score 0):

use `wbinfo -u` to list user.

then `id foo` to get `foo` id. (assume 498 is user id).

try adding a line like this in /etc/passwd

```
 foo:x:498:500::/home/foo:/bin/nologin
```

another custom is to create new AD group (or groups) for account allowed to log in, then restrict by adding

```
 require_membership_of = S-1-5-21-361....,S-1-6-....
```

in `/etc/security/pam_winbind.conf`

you get SID for group using

```
 wbinfo -g
```

to list group, then

```
 wbinfo -n "domain guests"
 S-1-5-21-3042011434-3993383375-693717967-514 SID_DOM_GROUP (2)
```